# C Program to check if every unique characters in a string have occurred an even or odd number of times

Tags: c, string

Sample input: aaxdxddd

Output: even

Sample input : aada

Output: odd

Sample input: aadssssdddd

Output: both

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    
    char s[1000];  
    int  i,j,k,count=0,n;

    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(s);
     
    int len = strlen(s);
    
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        count=1;
        
        if(s[i]){
            
            for(j=i+1;j<len;j++){   
              
                if(s[i]==s[j]){
                    count++;
                    s[j]='\0';
                }
            }  
                    printf(" '%c' = %d \n",s[i],count);
          
             if (count%2==0){
                printf("even\n");
                 //break;
             }
                 else if (count%2==1){
                     printf("odd\n");
                     //break;
                 }
        }
             
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

My problem to my code is that it determines each character if it occurred an even or odd number of times. What I want to happen is that it determines if all unique characters occurred an even, odd, or both even and odd number of times. Also I didn't write the entire code, I found a similar code and tried to revise it.

Comment: have an array of 26 ints, one for each letter of the alpha bet. every time you find a char incement its count by 1. The walk that array detecting 0, odd or even

Comment: If you only want to keep track of the parity, you only need 1 bit per character, just alternate.

Comment: @pm100 only 26?  There is no restriction on character or case in this requirement.

Comment: Is the input restricted to lowercase alpha characters as pm100 has assumed? If so it may considerably simplify the solution.

Comment: All characters are lowercase alphabetical characters only